# Как сделать поле только для чтения?

Tags: javascript, php, readonly

```
<input type="hidden" id="id" value="<?=$client['id']?>">
```

Сейчас поле скрытое, подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать его только для чтения.
Заранее спасибо

---

Сделал вот так,

```
<input contenteditable="false" id="id" value="<?=$client['id']?>">
```

не помогло.

Comment: Где? в php или JavaScript?

Comment: ну попробуй задать contenteditable="false" через html

Comment: Это JS. Здесь видно value="<?=$client['id']?>", что php вставлен в JS. Если я не ошибаюсь

Comment: Какой то странный вопрос..надо чтобы было видно его, но онли чтение ? type="text" readonly

Comment: Спасибо, не знал как применить readonly. А может скинуть какую-нибудь объяснение readonly, с чем едят и какие еще бывают его разновидности?

Comment: Подробнее можно в спецификациях html посмотреть, либо в справочниках например http://htmlbook.ru/html/input/readonly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="hidden" id="id" value="<?=$client['id']?>" readonly>
```

Answer (score 0):

Дай инпуту атрибут `contenteditable="false"` элемент станет только RO